# Spring OAuth2 custom request - put parameters on body like raw data

Tags: spring-security, http-headers, spring-security-oauth2

I am implementing a client with Spring Security OAuth2 to use resources through an API, I have to customize the request like this:

```
POST https://example.com/v2/oauth2/token HTTP / 1.1
Authorization: Basic xxxXXXXxxXXXXXXxXXxxXX
Content-Type: application / x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept: application / json; charset = UTF-8

grant_type = authorization_code & code = 12345678901234567890
```

Where: grant_type = authorization_code & code = 12345678901234567890
it is contained in the body as raw data.

How can I put the grant_type and code parameters on the body?

At the moment my code is formalized in this way:

```
AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails resource = new AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails ();
resource.setAccessTokenUri ( "https://example.com/v2/oauth2/token");
resource.setClientId ( "xxxxx");
resource.setClientSecret ( "xxxxx");
resource.setGrantType ( "authorization_code");
resource.setUseCurrentUri (false);
AccessTokenRequest atr = new DefaultAccessTokenRequest ();
atr.setPreservedState (new Object ());
atr.setAuthorizationCode(authCode);

AuthorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider provider = new AuthorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider ();

try {
OAuth2AccessToken accessToken = provider.obtainAccessToken (resource, atr);
}
catch (Exception e) {
System.out.println ("DEBUG" + e);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can use a filter to intercept the request to the token endpoint before the authorization server completes the process of authorization.

This is my implementation of OAuth2 using a json as a body instead of URL-encoded format.

https://github.com/aldwindelgado/spring-boot-oauth2-server/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/oauth2/server/JsonToUrlEncodedAuthenticationFilter.java

Answer (score 0):

Add `atr.setAuthorizationCode("12345678901234567890");` to set the auth code to the Access Token Request.

Comment: I forgot to paste it ... but it is indifferent, the parameter is put on the header and not on the body.

Comment: Well, the `AccessTokenRequest` is a `MultiValueMap` being passed into the request and converted into HTTP headers. I'm not sure if there's any other way but as per my understanding, you might have to build the request using `RestTemplate` or some other way. Again, just my opinion.